# Why does therubyracer fails to build on my Debian?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, build-process, debian

I want to update to rails 3.2, but the build process of therubyracer (0.9.9) fails. I've no clue what I've to do.

My environment: 
Debian Squeeze (2.6.32-5-amd64)

```
make
compiling v8_external.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_external.cpp:4:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::External]’:
v8_external.cpp:51:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_external.cpp: At global scope:
v8_external.cpp:10: warning: ‘<unnamed>::references’ defined but not used
compiling v8_context.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_context.cpp:2:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Context]’:
v8_context.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::ObjectTemplate]’:
v8_context.cpp:22:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value]’:
v8_context.cpp:23:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_value.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_value.cpp:1:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value]’:
v8_value.cpp:10:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_message.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_message.cpp:2:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Message]’:
v8_message.cpp:10:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_date.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_date.cpp:4:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Date]’:
v8_date.cpp:21:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_handle.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling v8_v8.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling v8_callbacks.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling v8_array.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_array.cpp:1:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Array]’:
v8_array.cpp:13:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_exception.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_exception.cpp:3:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::StackTrace]’:
v8_exception.cpp:48:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::StackFrame]’:
v8_exception.cpp:68:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_exception.cpp: At global scope:
v8_exception.cpp:10: warning: ‘<unnamed>::stack’ defined but not used
compiling v8_weakref.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling v8_debug.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling v8_function.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_function.cpp:5:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Function]’:
v8_function.cpp:13:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Array]’:
v8_function.cpp:23:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::String]’:
v8_function.cpp:49:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_object.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_object.cpp:1:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Object]’:
v8_object.cpp:17:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_locker.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
v8_locker.cpp: In function ‘VALUE<unnamed>::Lock::Delete(VALUE)’:
v8_locker.cpp:45: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
v8_locker.cpp: In function ‘VALUE<unnamed>::Unlock::Delete(VALUE)’:
v8_locker.cpp:85: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
compiling v8_script.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_script.cpp:2:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Script]’:
v8_script.cpp:25:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_string.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_string.cpp:3:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::String]’:
v8_string.cpp:13:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling rr.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
rr.cpp: In function ‘VALUE rr_define_finalizer(VALUE, void*, VALUE)’:
rr.cpp:48: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
In file included from rr.cpp:3:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value]’:
rr.cpp:159:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_template.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_template.cpp:2:
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Template]’:
v8_template.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::ObjectTemplate]’:
v8_template.cpp:45:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::FunctionTemplate]’:
v8_template.cpp:48:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function ‘v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Data]’:
v8_template.cpp:54:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
linking shared-object v8.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a(functexcept.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [v8.so] Error 1
```

### UPDATE

I've tried the following:

1. Downloaded a copy of the source `git clone https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer.git`
2. Added `$CPPFLAGS += " -fPIC"` to the `ext/v8/extconf.rb`
3. Built gem with `gem build therubyracer.gemspec`
4. Installed gem with `gem install therubyracer-0.9.9.gem`

Same error was shown to me! Issue: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/135

Comment: if you managed to build it, what error did you see ?

Comment: I could just compile version 0.9.8, never 0.9.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to run the version 0.9.8 as version 0.9.9. (solves not the real problem):

1. Clone therubyracer's source `git clone https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer.git`
2. Checkout tag v0.9.8 `git checkout v0.9.8`
3. Change version number in `./lib/v8/version.rb` to `0.9.9`
4. Build the gem `gem build therubyracer.gemspec`
5. Install the gem `gem install therubyracer-0.9.9.gem`

Answer (score 2):

On a debian (686 with amd64 kernel) I had to uninstall livb8, download the gem and recompile for my architecture

```
gem uninstall libv8
wget http://rubygems.org/downloads/libv8-3.3.10.4.gem
ARCHFLAG='-arch i386' gem install ./libv8-3.3.10.4.gem
ARCHFLAG='-arch i386' gem install therubyracer
```

Then therubyracer (0.10.1) installed fine.

Comment: This has solved my issue, but I can't make it work when deploying with capistrano + bundler. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

```
recompile with -fPIC
```

Have you tried adding `-fPIC` as an additional build flag? You can test it out in a gem install:

```
$ gem install therubyracer -- -fPIC
```

Or, with Bundler:

```
$ bundle config build.therubyracer -fPIC
```

It looks like someone else pointed it out in an [issue](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/135). You might want to check it out if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no success. Same problem. Your link doesn't help, too. Anyway, thanks!